# Time interval is inactive in trading view chart

Tags: charts, highcharts, trading

I am using trading view chart. Time interval is inactive before level "1D"

1 minute, 3 minutes, 15 minutes
and 
1 hour, 4 hour is inactive 
from D its active

how can i make interval minutes and hours active

Comment: Try to set [minRange](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.minRange) parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Post a `PrintScreen` picture for your trading **`Symbol`** showing these de-activated TimeFrame options together with a **`Help > About`** sub-window showing details.

Answer (score 0):

Just set `allButtonsEnabled`, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#rangeSelector.allButtonsEnabled).